# Probability of one pair of brothers sitting together

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> I have 10 kids which are 5 pairs of brothers sitting randomly across 5 tables, each table has two seats. What is the probability of only one couple sitting together?

Solving it with combinatorics alone (as it was done in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977513/arranging-5-pairs-of-brothers-in-ten-tables)) is complicated because After pairing the first couple I have too many options. So I was trying to think of the complement event which is only $\ 1 $ couple of brothers not sitting together, which is zero (because it can not be that only 1 couple are not sitting together). So what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: The complement is "not only one couple together " and differs from "only one couple not together ".

Comment: I don't think I understand..

Comment: You mean to say $5$ pairs of brothers and sisters? Is the order in which a pair sits on a given table significant?

Comment: Yes lets say brothers and sisters. the order in which a pair sits is insignificant

Comment: The complement of "only one couple together" is in this context: "a number of couples together that equals $0,2,3,4$ or $5$" (all numbers in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ except $1$). That is something else than "only one couple not together" or equivalently "exactly $4$ couples together".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start with another problem:

> I have $8$ kids which are $4$ pairs of brothers sitting randomly across $4$ tables, each table has two seats. What is the probability that **no** couple sits together?

Number the couples $1,2,3,4$ and let $B_{i}$ denote the event
that couple $i$ sits together.

Then to be found is $P\left(B_{1}^{\complement}\cap B_{2}^{\complement}\cap B_{3}^{\complement}\cap B_{4}^{\complement}\right)=1-P\left(B_{1}\cup B_{2}\cup B_{3}\cup B_{3}\right)$

Applying the principle of inclusion/exclusion and also symmetry we
find that this probability equals:

$$1-4P\left(B_{1}\right)+6P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\right)-4P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}\right)+P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}\cap B_{4}\right)$$

Here we find:

- $P\left(B_{1}\right)=\frac{1}{7}$
- $P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\right)=P\left(B_{2}\mid B_{1}\right)P\left(B_{2}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{7}$
- $P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}\right)=P\left(B_{3}\mid B_{1}\cap B_{2}\right)P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{7}$
- $P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}\cap B_{4}\right)=P\left(B_{4}\mid B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}\right)P\left(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3}\right)=\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{7}$

So we find: $$P\left(B_{1}^{\complement}\cap B_{2}^{\complement}\cap B_{3}^{\complement}\cap B_{4}^{\complement}\right)=1-4\cdot\frac{1}{7}+6\cdot\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{7}-4\cdot\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{7}=\frac{4}{7}$$

---

Now we step to the original problem.

Again number the couples $1,2,3,4,5$ and let $E_{i}$ denote the event that couple $i$ will sit together.

Further let $E$ denote the event that exactly one couple sits together.

Then $E$ is the union of the events:

- $E_{1}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\cap E_{5}^{\complement}$
- $E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\cap E_{5}^{\complement}$
- $E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\cap E_{5}^{\complement}$
- $E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}\cap E_{5}^{\complement}$
- $E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\cap E_{5}$.

These events are mutually excusive and equiprobable so that:

$$P\left(E\right)=5P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\cap E_{5}\right)=5P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\mid E_{5}\right)P\left(E_{5}\right)$$

Here $P\left(E_{5}\right)=\frac{1}{9}$ because - after placing one
brother on a chair - there are $9$ chairs left and only $1$ of them
results in couple $1$ at the same table by placing the other brother.

Working under condition $E_{5}$ there are $4$ tables left for the
remaining $4$ couples and we are back in the problem that was solved
first.

So $P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\mid E_{5}\right)$ equals the $P\left(B_{1}^{\complement}\cap B_{2}^{\complement}\cap B_{3}^{\complement}\cap B_{4}^{\complement}\right)$ that was calculated there and we end up with:

$$P\left(E\right)=P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\mid E_{5}\right)P\left(E_{5}\right)=\frac{4}{7}\frac{1}{9}=\frac{4}{63}$$

Comment: Thank you! this is really informative answer. I'm trying to apply what you taught me here to a  case of 2 couples sitting together. So if $\ E $ is the event of only two couples sitting together, it is true that $\ P(E) = 45 \cdot P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3^c \cap E_4^c \cap E_5^c) $ because they are excursive and equiprobable so $ P(E) = 45 P(E_3^c \cap E_4^c \cap E_5^c | E_1 \cap E_2)P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{7} $ ?

Comment: Not factor $45$ but factor $\binom52=10$. So $P(E)=10P(E_3^c\cap E_4^c\cap E_5^c\mid E_1\cap E_2)P(E_1\cap E_2)$. This with $P(E_1\cap E_2)=P(E_1)P(E_2\mid E_1)=\frac19\frac17$. To find the conditional probability (I haven't done that yet) you use the same strategy as above: find the probability that by $3$ couples and $3$ tables no couple will sit together.